# Whatsapp api using send messages to whatsapp from asp.net web application(c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using whatsapp api to create a application for sending messages to whatsapp from my application,which is developed in asp.net(c# application).I was stuck in this because i didn't get any request code or password for further process. I used this code

```
WhatsAppApi.WhatsApp wa = new WhatsAppApi.WhatsApp("+919048******", password, "Raveesh", true);
        wa.Connect();

        if (wa.ConnectionStatus == WhatsAppApi.ApiBase.CONNECTION_STATUS.CONNECTED)
        {
            wa.Login();
            wa.SendMessage("+9196569****", "This is a test message");
            wa.Disconnect();
        }
```

I didn't get any password,id,request code how can i get this.
i just used wart and chat api .net but i will not get any of these.please tell me how can i achieve my goal,i don't know more about this.

Comment: This API is no more exist. Stop proceeding further, you would not get anything & it will be just a wast of time.

Comment: hi then how can i do this,any other api available for this

Comment: is it possible now

Comment: After Facebook acquired WhatsApp it has stopped that kind of services.